# Is there a method in Firestore that could fetch a document and its adjacent documents?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In Firestore, we need to use something like `startAt` or `endAt` with `limit` to get either previous or preceding data from a given point in the list of documents within a collection.
We need to fetch twice to get adjacent documents (once for the data before and once for the data after) then we need to combine them in the list which could be error prone

I was wondering if there is a way to get the corresponding document with its adjacent documents in Flutter Firestore? Something like `.getDocumentWithAdjacent`

```
Firestore.instance.collection('restaurants').document(docId)
   .getDocumentWithAdjacent(previousCount: 3, afterCount: 6); // will fetch 10 documents
```

The command above will fetch 10 documents: 3 previous documents, the document itself, and 6 preceding documents.

Just further explanation & use cases:
Just like Instagram app for example, the user can tap on a post to see its detail. Then the user can scroll up and down to see the adjacent post details easily because when the user tap on a post, some of the data before and after that post also being loaded.

Another example: A restaurant search app that shows a list of restaurant in an area.
When a user tap somewhere in the middle of the list of restaurant, then the restaurant details is being displayed, but the user want to scroll (either horizontally or vertically) to see the adjacent restaurant in the list so we need to load the data for that also.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firestore does not have a concept of "adjacent" documents in the way that you describe.

What you can do instead is make two queries.  One for documents greater than a given document, then another for document less than the given.

Comment: Thanks Doug! I can only accept the answer 6 minutes later. Will come back soon. I also did post a feature request in github. Probably, if the Firebase team sees fit, there could be a method in the future to simplify the whole process into one fetch and return a list.